# Slice a python list from an end index to some begin index

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say for the python list

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

`a[2:5]` returns `[3, 4, 5]`

but to slice from the end to the beginning such that the list becomes circular I tried the following:

```
a[-1:1]
a[-2:-5]
a[5:2]
```

all of which returned `[]`

Is there a pythonic way to get this done?

(A naive approach can be to reverse the list if the indices are in reverse order, but is there a optimal one line way inbuilt by python)

Thank you

Comment: in case of the above 3 inputs, output -> `[7, 1]`

Comment: The question related to wrapping does the work perfectly, thanks